# Representing a list of "tuples" in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The data coming from the backend has the following (**embedded**) field (this belongs to a "contact" object) (`json`):

```
"phone_numbers" : [ ["mobile", "43534545354"], ["home", "4356346"] ]
```

The format is then just a simple list of phone number elements, in turn two-element lists, with these two fields:

- string: telephone type
- string: telephone number

I would like to offer the possibility in my ember application to:

- delete a phonenumber
- add a phonenumber, specifying telephone type (selected from a drop-down) and telephone number
- remove all phone numbers

How can I represent `phone_numbers` using ember objects, in order to easily implement these two actions?

I have started by using `DS.attr('raw')`, but I guess I will have to implement much generic functionality (like: extract phone from array, extract phone type, extract phone number, ...). Is there a better aproach? This is my current take:

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
    title         : DS.attr('string'),
    first_name    : DS.attr('string'),
    surname1      : DS.attr('string'),
    surname2      : DS.attr('string'),
    phone_numbers : DS.attr('raw'),
});
```

### EDIT

Following the explanation [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_creating-custom-transformations), I have started defining a custom transform:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('phoneNumber', {
    serialize: function(value) {
        return [value.get('type'), value.get('number')];
    },
    deserialize: function(value) {
        return Ember.create({ type: value[0], number: value[1] });
    }
});

App.PhoneNumber = DS.Model.extend({
    position: DS.attr('phoneNumber')
});
```

The problem that I have is that I do not know how to use this new `phoneNumber` type to define a list of `phone_numbers`:

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    phone_numbers : list of App.PhoneNumber ???
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it by doing:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('phoneNumbers', {
    serialize: function(data) {
        var phonenumbers = [], phonenumber;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            phonenumber = data[i];
            phonenumbers.push([phonenumber.get('type'), phonenumber.get('number')]);
        }
        return phonenumbers;
    },
    deserialize: function(phonenumbers) {
        var data = Ember.A(), phonenumber;
        for (var i = 0; i < phonenumbers.length; i++) {
            phonenumber = phonenumbers[i];
            data.push(Ember.create({ type: phonenumber[0], number: phonenumber[1] }));
        }
        return data;
    }
});

App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    phone_numbers : DS.attr('phoneNumbers'),
});
```