# How to migrate a transform for ember-data-1.0.0.beta6?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This was working for ember-data-0.0.14:

```
// Used to represent a list of strings, for example the multilocators: [ "43534545354", "4356346" ]
// Used for phone_numers, emails and addresses
// See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18019074/647991
SettingsApp.register('transform:listOfStringsTransform', {
    serialize: function(data) {
        var elements = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            elements.push(data[i]);
        }
        if (DEBUG) { console.log('listOfStringsTransform.serialize > data=%o -> elements=%o', data, elements); }
        return elements;
    },
    deserialize: function(elements) {
        var data = Ember.A();
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            data.push(elements[i]);
        }
        if (DEBUG) { console.log('listOfStringsTransform.deserialize > elements=%o -> data=%o', elements, data); }
        return data;
    }
});
```

But now, I get:

```
Error while loading route: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'create'
    at instantiate (http://localhost:9001/bower/ember/ember.js:10975:26)
    at Object.Container.lookup (http://localhost:9001/bower/ember/ember.js:10547:21)
    at DS.JSONSerializer.Ember.Object.extend.transformFor (http://localhost:9001/bower/ember-data/ember-data.js:869:36)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9001/bower/ember-data/ember-data.js:206:28)
    at http://localhost:9001/bower/ember-data/ember-data.js:5780:16
    at http://localhost:9001/bower/ember/ember.js:3194:16
    at Object.OrderedSet.forEach (http://localhost:9001/bower/ember/ember.js:3037:10)
    at Object.Map.forEach (http://localhost:9001/bower/ember/ember.js:3192:10)
    at Function.DS.Model.reopenClass.eachTransformedAttribute (http://localhost:9001/bower/ember-data/ember-data.js:5779:40)
    at DS.JSONSerializer.Ember.Object.extend.applyTransforms (http://localhost:9001/bower/ember-data/ember-data.js:205:10) ember.js:3287
```

There is a single test for register transform in the ember-data code base, and that is very simple, so it does not work as reference. How can I adapt this working code to the new ember-data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transform must be an instance of `DS.Transform.extend({})`